# Can I squeeze my own program between the preprocessor and compiler?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, g++, c-preprocessor

Is this a stupid question, or can I specify g++ to use a program between the preprocessor and compiler?

Alternatively, I know that I can just run the preprocessor on a file (hence all the files). Then I am guessing there is a switch to run only the compiler. So I can manually invoke these two and put my program between. If so, how do I run compiler (and linker?) only?

I'd rather prefer the first method as our builder would probably not agree with me :).

Comment: Even if you couldn't find an option in your compiler to skip preprocessing, you can always just run the preprocessed code through the whole process.  The preprocessor will simply have nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run an alternative preprocessor, the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) suggests using `-no-integrated-cpp` and `-B`.

I have no experience with these, so I suggest you read the relevant parts in [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

---

Alternatively, you can run the compiler without invoking the preprocessor by telling g++ that the language is "preprocessed C++":

```
g++ -x c++-cpp-output
```

g++ will also recognize files with the suffix `.ii` as preprocessed C++, so the pipeline becomes:

```
source.cpp -> source.ii: g++ -o source.ii -E source.cpp
source.ii -> source.custom.ii: <custom step>
source.custom.ii -> source.o: g++ -o source.o -c source.custom.ii
source.o -> source: g++ -o source source.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the -Xpreprocessor option, this allows you to define new pre-processor interpretations